# Docker compose in another directory affects other containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have an issue. I used my `docker-compose` file for one project. Then I copied it to another directory in order to run another containers. But whenever I do that it recreates existing containers or in case I use the down command it also destroys containers from another directory, what could be wrong?

Here is my configuration.

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - "5440:5432"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: rootme
    volumes:
      - pgadmin:/root/.pgadmin
    ports:
      - "8440:80"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres:
  pgadmin:
```

For example when I run `docker-compose up -d` from another directory it recreates containers

```
Recreating docker_postgres_1 ... done
Recreating docker_pgadmin_1  ... done
```

What is the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Docker Compose attaches a name prefix to everything it creates, but the default prefix is just based on the basename of the current directory.  If you have a layout like

```
projectA
+-- docker
|   \-- docker-compose.yml
projectB
\-- docker
    \-- docker-compose.yml
```

then both `docker-compose` instances will think the project name is just `docker` (the name of the directory containing `docker-compose.yml`) and create container names like, for example, `docker_postgres_1`.

You can get around this by either renaming one of the directories, using the [`docker-compose -p` option](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/#use--p-to-specify-a-project-name), or [setting a `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` environment variable](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name).  It wouldn't be unusual to see a `docker-compose.yml` file in the top-level directory of a project and that might help disambiguate things.

Comment: Why.. Why does docker-compose do this %) This is clearly not the intention. I go into trouble to assign unique container names in the compose files and here comes docker-compose and shits all over them. Moreover, it seems like it does this only for format 3+. Anyway, setting unique service names fixes the problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it occurs because of the containers on the previous project continue running while you try up the new project.

Try to stop the containers on the previous folder before upon the current.

Comment: Thank for the answer, however I need to run multiple containers of the same type simultiniously